# postgresql, узнать количество записей после определенной записи

Tags: postgresql

Всем доброе утро, возникла следующая задача:
В общем, Мне нужно получить количество записей со статусом 1841, количество записей должно быть 0. Почему 0? Если после 1841 идет статус 1840 - количество записей должно быть 0. Как можно реализовать такой запрос? То есть, если после статуса 1841 идет какой-либо другой статус - то количество записей должно быть нулю!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT id, date, credit_status
FROM credit_snapshot
WHERE credit_id = 107644.
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Что именно значит "после"? Какие условия сортировки выборки? Что если по 1841 идёт 1842? 1843? А 1839? Опишите задачу точнее.

Comment: В нашем случае идет две записи 1840, потом 5 записей 1841, после уже 1840. Если после 1841 нет никакого больше статуса - то выдать число 5(у нас же 5 записей со статусом 1841) Если после 1841 идет КАКОЙ-ЛИБО другой статус - выдавать 0. В нашем случае последняя запись - 1840, поэтому 0

Comment: Пока не определён порядок сортировки - понятий "перед" и "после" не существует. Таблица - это куча, а порядок вывод записей без указания сортировки - полностью случаен и в любой момент имеет право измениться. В показанных данных никакой сортировки не наблюдается. Поэтому вопрос лишён смысла.

Comment: Ребят, у меня есть поле id(auto_increment), там стандартно ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: Не поленитесь заменить пример данных. И не фотографией, а обычным форматированным текстом.

Comment: Добавил запрос в описание.

Comment: Возможная реализация: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=59fe92102a870af301f01150a82fa27d).

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Уточните - надо вообще количество записей с указанным статусом, или только в последней группе? Т.е. если статусы идут 1-1841-1-1841, нужно получить 1 или 2?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте например так:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN credit_status=1841 
        THEN (SELECT count(*) FROM credit_snapshot WHERE credit_id = 107644 AND credit_status = 1841) 
        ELSE 0 
    END 
FROM credit_snapshot WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) from credit_snapshot WHERE credit_id = 107644)
```

Запрос вернет кол-во записей со статусом 1841, если в последней записи (при максимальном id) `credit_status = 1841`, это значит, что после него нет больше никаких статусов. Если там статус другой, то вернет 0.

Если нужно что-то иное, уточните задачу более конкретно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все отлично